# Java + Spark + Oozie - How to ensure spark job executes on a specific node

Tags: java, apache-spark, oozie, oozie-workflow

We are using Oozie to schedule spark job workflows. 
We are executing multiple spark-jobs (on cluster YARN).

One of the job is data-import-job where we are importing data from Linux File System to the HDFS.

Our problem is, when oozie schedules a job, any node in the cluster can work as master node, but the data is present on only node-1.

So we want to ensure that node-1 should always be taken as the master node when data-import-job is being run.

Can we achieve this?

Regards
Anuj Mehra

Comment: Anuj, hope you refers master means driver.  If you are using Spark action to read data, rdd can access in executors. Could you please clarify are you using Java action or any other action n your workflow.

Comment: In theory, with a recent version of Hadoop, you could set a "tag" on your silly specific node and find a way to tell YARN to run that specific job on a "tagged" node (i.e. just that one in your case). But I don't know in detail which job property to set -- and to set again with  `oozie.launcher.` prefix so that Oozie applies it to the Laucher itself  _(because that's how it is called)_ and not only to its slave YARN jobs.

Comment: But it would be way more efficient to dump the data directly from source to HDFS to begin with -- e.g. with WebHDFS (REST API). Works from any source that can run HTTP PUT with `curl` or with a bit of code (I've done it with Java, Powershell, Excel macros...)

Comment: We have chosen the solution to remove the data import flow from Oozie. We are now importing data from SFTP (zip files). Unzip that data on Linux FS, then push that data to HDFS. After data has been pushed to HDFS, oozie workflow is triggered.